# Fetch images randomly from directory?

Tags: php, image, random

I am no too proficient in PHP yet and I have this code which works so far.

```
<?php 
$id = JRequest::getInt('id');
$dirname = "media/k2/galleries/{$id}/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
$rand = array_rand($dirname);
?>
<?php foreach($images as $image): ?>

<li><span class="shadowborder"><img src="<?php echo $image ?>" /></span>    </li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I have tried to add an array, I know $images and $image should be swapped out but as you can see but I cannot get it to gel, what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: you have to fetch all and create array then you can fetch them random.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Show images in random order?

Comment: yes, fetch all images in directory then display one by one at random. The above code works but it shows then by filename. So literally I need to add the random function.

Comment: I added the $rand = array_rand($dirname); but as of yet it is not being used. And I have obviously omitted the wrapping UL tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) for this:

```
$id = JRequest::getInt('id');
$dirname = "media/k2/galleries/{$id}/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
shuffle($images);
?>
<?php foreach($images as $image): ?>

<li><span class="shadowborder"><img src="<?php echo $image ?>" /></span>    </li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: so simple, any drawbacks?

Comment: Only drawback of shuffle is that it doesn't maintain the keys.

Comment: But it will continue and repeat using the same shuffled order or would it keep shuffling?

Comment: @user3206244 It will produce a new random order each time. Most likely it won't be the same.

Comment: good enough for this use - thanks a stack! One line, done.. I am still learning how to leverage arrays etc but including php gets a bit tricky - many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the '[Glob](http://se.php.net/glob)' function in partnership with `array_rand()` to achieve this:

```
<img src="
    <?php
        $id = JRequest::getInt('id');
        $imagesDir = 'media/k2/galleries/{$id}/';
        $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
        $randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
        echo $randomImage;
    ?>
">
```

You can modify which file-types to 'allow' via changing (adding/removing) this part:
 `'*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}`

---

Feel free to ask any further questions.

Comment: thanks a stack! What is the difference between using glob and an array_rand vs just shuffle on $images?

Comment: I read about using array_rand and that it leaves the arrays index in tact and chooses one index at random whereas shuffle actually reorders the indexes and select one. But surely the random continues over the reordered indexes?